# What dialect/accent in the UK do people not say the word "the"

Tags: dialects, accent, british-english

I know a decent amount about different dialects in the UK, and usually recognize and identify them, but I heard one today that took me by surprise. I was watching a TV show, and this family, who I think are from Yorkshire (certainly somewhere in the North), had a very interesting way of speaking. At certain times they seem to not say "the" in places where it would be natural. "Go and walk the dog" became "go and walk dog". "Say to me all the time" became "Say to me all time".

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLpCaDBghb8&t=11m30s) the video with time stamps.

[11:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLpCaDBghb8&t=11m30s) "Mum's asked you to walk dog, now get your clothes on and walk dog"

[11:45](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLpCaDBghb8&t=11m45s) "He used to say to me all time ..."

[30:31](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLpCaDBghb8&t=30m31s) "You don't have to be joined at hip"

What accent/dialect is this? Is this feature common in there?

Comment: Yes, Yorkshire people are often represented as reducing _the_ to a bare 't' sound - "walk t'dog".

Answer (score 11):

*The* is often reduced in Yorkshire dialect, to varying degrees.

It is most commonly reduced to an unreleased stop, usually glottal, but sometimes elsewhere in the mouth (eg "walk t'dog" /wɔkɂdɒg/ - there is usually no /t/ sound, despite the customary spelling).

But in informal contexts, this "catch" almost disappears, and it can sound like /wɔkdɒg/ "walk dog".

See this discussion in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_article_reduction#Phonetics).

Comment: I've recently been dabbling in the shallows of learning Scottish gaelic, where I have discovered that the 'gaelic article', in certain circumstances, 'an-t'. I couldn't help but half wonder if the North of England 'stopped-t article' bore some ancestral relationship to the gaelic article.

Comment: @Spagirl I'm going to say that's definitely not the case. Gaelic was not in any way the original tongue of the region - before English and Danish languages they spoke Brittonic.

Comment: Yup. As it says in the Wikipedia: except around Kingston-upon-Hull where it is reduced to just about nothing. Its a Ded Bod